# CSS Letter Spacing extends the Button to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and I've added a button, when hovered the letter spacing will increase slightly, the issue is that when this happens, the letter width increases the width of the button to the right, decentering it from where it was when not hovered.

Run it and see what I mean, I would like the button to get wider but keep its center position, kind of like  the title, how can I do that?

Code:

```css
header {
  background: rgb(53,65,83);
  margin:-8px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color:aliceblue;
  letter-spacing: 1cap;
  align-content: center;
}

body {
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(240, 241, 248);
}

button {
  margin-left:20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(42, 43, 54);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border: 1px solid rgb(42, 43, 54);
  float: left;
}
button:hover {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: rgb(184, 186, 203);
  color: rgb(42, 43, 54);
}
button:active {
  scale: 90%;
}

.buttons {
  align-content: center;
}

h4 {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px rgb(138, 138, 138);
  
  transform: translateY(0px);
  border: 3px double  rgb(153, 156, 181);
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  transition: transform 0.4s, border 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
}
h4:hover {
  transform: translateY(4px);
  border: 3px double rgb(111, 112, 126);
  transition: transform 0.4s, border 0.4s, 0.4s;
}
h4::selection {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
  user-select: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  transition: letter-spacing 0.2s;
}
.title:hover {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  transition: letter-spacing 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>J-ak-e</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>Socials</button>
    </div>
    <div class="title">J-ak-e</div>
  </header>
  <h4>About me:</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have transition: scaleY instead of transform: scaleY

Comment: @SupreetT my bad, that line of code has nothing to do with the issue, I forgot to remove it.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the button can't extend to the left since that's the edge of the container. I would wrap the button around it's own container (which you already have as .buttons), with a larger width, centralize the buttons inside it's container, and then expand it.

Comment: I've updated the code with what you've said, it still acts the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the button doesn't have space to grow on the left, so it only grows to the right. By wrapping the button in a container of large width, and centering it within the container, it'll have space inside it's parent to grow to both sides.

**Grid Solution**
Make the `header` a grid, with specified column sizes

```css
header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
    place-items: center;
}
```

This gives the same effect as a container around the button, and is centered inside of it due to `place-items: center`.

Comment: Thank you so much <333, I've saved this answer for the future, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform: scale();` instead of `letter-spacing`.

```css
header {
  background: rgb(53,65,83);
  margin:-8px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color:aliceblue;
  letter-spacing: 1cap;
  align-content: center;
}

body {
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(240, 241, 248);
}

button {
  margin-left:20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(42, 43, 54);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border: 1px solid rgb(42, 43, 54);
  float: left;
}
button:hover {
  /* letter-spacing: 2px; */
  transform: scale(1.2); 
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: rgb(184, 186, 203);
  color: rgb(42, 43, 54);
}
button:active {
  scale: 90%;
}

.buttons {
  align-content: center;
}

h4 {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px rgb(138, 138, 138);
  
  transform: translateY(0px);
  border: 3px double  rgb(153, 156, 181);
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  transition: transform 0.4s, border 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
}
h4:hover {
  transform: translateY(4px);
  border: 3px double rgb(111, 112, 126);
  transition: transform 0.4s, border 0.4s, 0.4s;
}
h4::selection {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
  user-select: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  transition: letter-spacing 0.2s;
}
.title:hover {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  transition: letter-spacing 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button>Socials</button>
    </div>
    <div class="title">J-ak-e</div>
    </header>
<h4>About me:</h2>
```

Comment: I specifically want to space the letters, so letter spacing is perfect

Comment: You can do it both, just activate the ```letter-spacing``` then you can see it will transform while centered.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you are trying to get to. Ideally, hovering on any element should not disturb the other elements. That is the way to good UX.

```css
header {
  background: rgb(53, 65, 83);
  margin: -8px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: aliceblue;
  letter-spacing: 1cap;
  align-content: center;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(240, 241, 248);
}

button {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(42, 43, 54);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border: 1px solid rgb(42, 43, 54);
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

button:hover,
button::after {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: rgb(184, 186, 203);
  color: rgb(42, 43, 54);
}

button::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

button::before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

button:active {
  scale: 90%;
}

.buttons {
  align-content: center;
}

h4 {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px rgb(138, 138, 138);
  transform: translateY(0px);
  border: 3px double rgb(153, 156, 181);
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  transition: transform 0.4s, border 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
}

h4:hover {
  transform: translateY(4px);
  border: 3px double rgb(111, 112, 126);
  transition: transform 0.4s, border 0.4s, 0.4s;
}

h4::selection {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
  user-select: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  transition: letter-spacing 0.2s;
}

.title:hover {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  transition: letter-spacing 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>J-ak-e</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button data-title="Socials"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="title">J-ak-e</div>
  </header>
  <h4>About me:</h2>
</body>

</html>
```